# Selecting a IDs with specified column attributes

Tags: r

The data in which I am trying to make my selection looks like

```
   ID Field  Rank
8    6 Other  Prof
9    6 Other  Prof
13   7 Other Assoc
16   7 Other Assoc
17   7 Other  Prof
18   8 Other Assoc
19   8 Other Assoc
22   9 Other Assoc
23   9 Other Assoc
24   9 Other  Prof
```

I am trying to create a new variable that contains all the rows of the people(ID) that have been promoted from 'Assoc' to 'Prof'. For example I would like my new variable to look like

```
   ID Field  Rank
13   7 Other Assoc
16   7 Other Assoc
17   7 Other  Prof
22   9 Other Assoc
23   9 Other Assoc
24   9 Other  Prof
```

I have tried the subset function but with no luck.

Is there a function in R that can do this? If not, how can this be achieved.

EDIT: here, is the result from `dput()`. Note I left out the "Field" variable since it does not contain any information in this example.

```
 df.promotion <- structure(list(id = c(6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9), rank = structure(c(2L, 
 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Assoc", "Prof"
 ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "rank"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I made this example reproducible for you and others, try to do so too next time, e.g. by using dput().

Comment: either mine or yours is not needed anymore :)

Comment: Thanks, I have left yours in. Still getting used to posting and R.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xtabs` to tabulate your data by `ID` and `Rank`:

```
tab <- xtabs(~ID+Rank,dfr)
tab
   Rank
ID  Assoc Prof
  6     0    2
  7     2    1
  8     2    0
  9     2    1
```

You want the ones where no zero occurs:

```
subset(dfr,ID %in% rownames(tab[as.logical(apply(tab,1,prod)),]))
   ID Field  Rank
13  7 Other Assoc
16  7 Other Assoc
17  7 Other  Prof
22  9 Other Assoc
23  9 Other Assoc
24  9 Other  Prof
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a play with this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: would something like `rownames(tab)[apply(tab!=0,1,all)]` be clearer ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, that looks much better

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks. I used the first example you provided and much success.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly easy to understand approach that uses your first inclination to do this using `subset()`:

I create `p` which is the `id` of everyone who's a Prof. Then I create `a` which is everyone who's an associate. Then using `%in%` we select everyone who's been both an Assoc and a Prof. That gives me a set of keys which I can then use to subset the initial data.frame.

```
p <- unique(subset(df.promotion, rank=="Prof")$id)
a <- unique(subset(df.promotion, rank=="Assoc")$id)

mySet <- a[a %in% p]
subset(df.promotion, id %in% mySet)
```

Comment: Worked as equally as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this with base R (though `plyr` is beckoning):
**Edit** adapted + tested to the newly provided `dput` output...

```
dfr<-df.promotion #just so I don't have to change too much below
colnames(dfr)<-c("ID", "Rank") #just so I don't have to change too much below
promotedIDs<-unique(dfr$ID)[sapply(unique(dfr$ID), function(curID){
  hasBoth<-(sum(is.na(match(c("Assoc", "Prof"), dfr$Rank[dfr$ID==curID]))) == 0)
})]
result<-dfr[dfr$ID %in% promotedIDs,]
```

I check, with `match` whether both "Prof" and "Assoc" are in the list of Ranks for each ID. Note that `match` returns `NA` if a value is not found, so counting the number of `NA`s is a way of finding out whether both matched.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the customary one liner using `plyr`. The code works by (a) splitting the data frame by id, and  (b) choosing only those `subsets` with greater than 1 unique rank (which is a proxy for promotion)

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df.promotion, .(id), subset, length(unique(rank)) > 1)
```